# Translation of "quite a lot"

Tags: traduction, adjectifs

"There are quite a lot of cats in the garden."

Can "quite a lot" be translated directly as *assez beaucoup*?

> Il y a **assez beaucoup** de chats dans le jardin.

What about translating with *pas mal*?

> Il y a **pas mal** de chats dans le jardin.

I'm not sure if with *pas mal* we should use *de chats* or *des chats*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Pas mal*" captures quite correctly the meaning of "*quite a lot*", but it's slightly informal (just a little bit). And like *beaucoup*, it's followed by **de**, not **des**.

*Assez beaucoup* is not correct.

Answer (score -1):

Il y a quand même beaucoup de chats dans le jardin